# Power Query - Add Column CountIF across two tables ie =COUNTIF(People[CityId],[@Id])

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have  two tables in PowerQuery `City` and `People`.

**CITY**

```
Id, Name
 1, Brisbane
 2, Sydney
 3, Melbourne
```

**PEOPLE**

```
Id, Name,  CityId
 1, Jay,   1
 2, Sam,   2
 3, Paul,  1
 4, Sarah, 3
```

I'd like to add a column to City that shows a count of how many people belong to that city. So far I have:

```
Table.AddColumn(City, "People.Count", each
    Table.RowCount(
        Table.SelectRows(
            People, 
            each [CityId] = [Id]
        )
    )
)
```

This returns all zeros in the new column. If I replace `[Id]` with `1` then I get `2`.

It appears the `[]` references the value on the current row but on the same table. Is there a way I can write it as

```
Table.AddColumn(City, "People.Count", each 
    Table.RowCount(
        Table.SelectRows(
            People, 
            each People[CityId] = City[Id]
        )
    )
)
```

In Excel this would be as basic as

`=COUNTIF(People[CityId],[@Id])`

and then pulled down the new column in **PEOPLE** (as per attached .xlsx)

Seems simple enough but absolutely stuck! Eeek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build a Query that starts from PEOPLE, and then Groups By City and calculates a Count.

Then I would Merge the CITY query with that new Query and expand the Count column.

No code or formulas are required - it's actually simpler than Excel formulas.

Comment: Excellent! That has worked. I am going to play around with this a little more and see if I can do it using a function so that I don't have to create a new query. Will post back with a follow up answer but have marked yours correct :) Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, now I see what you're after. There's a nifty trick to do it with a simple column:

```
= Table.AddColumn(City, "People.Count", each let Id=[Id] in Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(People, each [CityId] = Id)))
```

You need to define the column name as a variable in order to "leave" the current "context" you're in (People's table).

Comment: This worked for me. I was even able to include multiple conditions i.e. checks on multiple fields of People equivalent table by joining them with and operator. Thanks a lot for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are other answers about how to write this differently, but the most general solution here is probably to remove the nested [`each`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt185361.aspx) syntax.

It might be helpful to see that your query

```
Table.AddColumn(
    City,
    "People.Count", each 
      Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(
        People, 
        each [CityId] = [Id])))
```

is syntactic sugar for this rewritten version. In the `_[CityId] = _[Id]` expression, the `_` variable is bound the innermost parameter, and the outermost `_` isn't used:

```
Table.AddColumn(
    City,
    "People.Count", (_) =>
      Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(
        People, 
        (_) => _[CityId] = _[Id])))
```

If you ever have nested `each` expressions, I'd change the outer `each` to a function with a real variable name, like this:

```
Table.AddColumn(
    City,
    "People.Count", (CityRow)  =>
      Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(
        People, 
        each [CityId] = CityRow[Id])))
```